# Regex to match within brackets in vim

Tags: regex, vim

Let's say I have the following text:

```
new_item['uid']
```

And I want to capture everything within the `[` ... `]`. So in this case grab the `'uid'`. Normally I could use something like:

- [`\[([^\]]+)]`](https://regex101.com/r/AFDnTX/1)

To match this (start with the opening bracket and get everything until the closing bracket). But without the character classes, or negated character class in vim, how would I do something similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have a capture group with `(..)`, you need the verymagic mode, otherwise you have to escape the `(` and `)`, similar to the BRE.

So both give the matched part in `\1`:

```
\[\([^]]*\)
```

and (`\v` tells vim to match in verymagic mode)

```
\v\[([^]]*)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `.\{-}` in place of `.*?` to make a lazy dot match:

```
\[(.\{-})\]
```

Comment: thanks, could you please explain what `{-}` does? I couldn't find it in the vim help.

Comment: Is that the vim equivalent of `*?` -- `\{-}
matches 0 or more of the preceding atom, as few as possible`. (Does vim not allow doing `*?` ?

Answer (score 0):

in addition to the other answers, you could use `\v\[\zs.{-}\ze\]` to only highlight the text within `\zs` and `\ze`, see `:h \ze`

Comment: thanks. Is `{-}` the same as doing `*?` ? Or what exactly does `{-}` do?

Comment: also, what's the difference between using `\zs...\ze` and a capturing group?

Comment: in vim nogreedy is `{-}`, in perl it's `*?`. `\zs` only changes highlighting, if you are searching for things. Use capturing groups, if you want to substitute